# program that among the given numbers finds one that is different in evenness, and return a position of this number

Tags: python

Bob is preparing to pass IQ test. The most frequent task in this test is to find out which one of the given numbers differs from the others. Bob observed that one number usually differs from the others in evenness. Help Bob — to check his answers, he needs a program that among the given numbers finds one that is different in evenness, and return a position of this number.

! Keep in mind that your task is to help Bob solve a real IQ test, which means indexes of the elements start from 1 (not 0)

### Examples :

iq_test("2 4 7 8 10") => 3 // Third number is odd, while the rest of the numbers are even

iq_test("1 2 1 1") => 2 // Second number is even, while the rest of the numbers are odd

My Code:

```
def iq_test(a):
b=[]
c=[]
for i in range(len(a)):

    if a[i]%2 == 0:
        b.append(a[i])
    else:
        c.append(a[i])

if len(b)==1:
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if [a[i]]==b:
            return i+1 
if len(c)==1:
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if [a[i]]==c:
            return i+1
```

This works for the given inputs in my IDE, but when I put it in webpage IDE I obtain

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    Test.assert_equals(iq_test("2 4 7 8 10"),3)
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 6, in iq_test
    if a[i]%2 == 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What is the mistake here? Is my code correct?

Comment: a = "2 4 7 8 10"  is string not a list

Comment: I don't know how it worked in any case, because you need to convert the numbers to integers first. Try adding this as the first line in the function `a = [int(i) for i in a.split()]`.

Comment: `a` is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter given to your function is `"2 4 7 8 10"`. You're iterating over that string and applying a modulo operation, which throws the error you're seeing since Python doesn't do automatic type conversion and can't apply a module to the string `"2"` (and, if it did, would throw an error at the second iteration when it'd try to apply the modulo operation to `" "`).

The simplest fix here is to check if it's not a space, then convert to int before the module:

```
for (i in range (len(a)):
    if a[i] != " ":
        if int(a[i])%2 == 0:
            b.append(a[i])
...
```

By the way, the index, and range above is not neccessary for strings. You can also iterate over the string directly:

```
for char in a:
    if char != " ":
        if int(char)%2 == 0:
            b.append(char)
...
```

You could also [split](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/split.html) the string into an array and iterate over that:

```
array = a.split(" ") # results in ["2","4","7","8","10"]
for (item in array):
    if int(item)%2 == 0:
        b.append(item)
...
```

In a real world application, I would also opt to check if the character at the current position is convertible to int, but for your case this solution is sufficient.

Also, as someone who recently looked over their own assignments from the first two semesters, get into the habit of using explicitly named variables. e.g instead of `b` use `evenNumbers` and instead of `c` use `oddNumbers`. This makes your code a lot more readable and better to understand what you did and why.

Answer (score 0):

```
def iq_test(numbers):
    lst = numbers.split()
    evens = []
    odds = []
    for i in lst:
        if int(i) % 2 == 0:
            evens.append(int(i))
        else:
            odds.append(int(i))

    if len(evens) == 1:
        for i in lst:
            if int(i) == evens[0]:
                return lst.index(i)+1

    if len(odds) == 1:
        for i in lst:
            if int(i) == odds[0]:
                return lst.index(i)+1
```

I got it right

Comment: Hey how is this, I got it right, do i need to make any changes, if you have any doubt in my code just reply me...